# Margin-left doesn’t change with media query

Tags: css, media-queries

In the media query I aske to position nav bar at the bottom and remove the margin-lef of the main section.
The media query make the job for the nav bar but not for the margin-left.
https://codepen.io/ALL9000/pen/yLzQKmv?editors=1000
What’s wrong. ?

```
@media (max-width: 777px) {
  nav {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #main-doc {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to put the media-query at the end of the CSS.
You default styling for #main-doc comes after the media-query, so overrides it.
It should look like this:

```
#main-doc {
  margin-left: 290px;
}

@media (max-width: 777px) {
  nav {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #main-doc {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your hepl.

Answer (score -1):

As you define the `#main-doc {margin-left: 290px;}` after the `@media` query it overwrites the media. if you open your browser developer console you can see the `@media` appears in smaller sizes but does not take effects. so you can just move the `#main-doc {margin-left: 290px;}` before `@media` or use the `!important` keyword to tell the browse 'whenever this media appears its more important. It's a best practice not to use `!important` too much cuz it can overwrite and cuz damage somewhere else.

```
#main-doc {
  margin-left: 290px;
}
@media (max-width: 777px) {
      nav {
        display: block;
        position: static;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #main-doc {
        margin-left: 0px;
      }
    }
```

OR

```
@media (max-width: 777px) {
  nav {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #main-doc {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
  }
}
 #main-doc {
      margin-left: 290px;
 }
```

Comment: Do not use `!important`. There is no reason. We don't know what OP's other CSS looks like. It could be the media query is before the default styles.

Comment: @disinfor I just edit my answer. it's a good practice not to use `!important` too much.

Comment: thank you for your help.